# Implementation of property:plotArea.window.start and end for VizFrame bar chart

Tags: sapui5

E.g. I would like to display the end of the data in the VizFrame (it must be done not later than onAfterRendering event):

[image]

I have working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/BHTk4Zmtp33YlaepDydM?p=preview):

```
oVizFrame.getVizProperties().plotArea.window.start = {feedAxisLabels: {'Country': 'Finland'}};
oVizFrame.getVizProperties().plotArea.window.end = {feedAxisLabels: {'Country': 'Poland'}};
```

But  I still get top of the chart:

[image]

Please, is it possible to do it with properties of Vizframe [plotArea.window.start](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Bar%20%20(15)/Bar%20Chart/) and plotArea.window.end? According to this [manual](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/zoom/) it should be possible, but there is just horizontal example (so I am not sure, if it also works vertically). [Here](http://jsbin.com/tolowifibi/1/edit?html,output) is working example for the line chart (horizontal), but I need this for bar chart (vertically).

I would be really glad for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change feedAxisLabels to categoryAxis, so it will look like...

```
oVizFrame.getVizProperties().plotArea.window.start = {categoryAxis: {'Country': 'Finland'}};
oVizFrame.getVizProperties().plotArea.window.end = {categoryAxis: {'Country': 'Poland'}};
```

Have forked your plunker and made the [change here](https://plnkr.co/edit/S5gupl6vf1INPX9d1Cj0?p=preview)